# TextBox.Text [ 1 | 2 ] -> PictureBox { 1 | 2 }.Color = SomeColor?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, variables

I'm making a small tool. I just want to know if the `switch` in the code below is the quickest/best way to achieve this? In PHP, I'd reference the variable name dynamically like `$Stop{int Stop} -> $BackColor = "Color"`

[image: CSSGM]

```
public void Populate(Color Color, int Stop)
{
    Colour.BackColor = Color;             // Bottom left - PictureBox
    Hex.Text = ARGBToHex(Color.ToArgb()); // Hex (#703919) - TextBox
    Red.Text = Color.R.ToString();        // Red (153) - TextBox
    Green.Text = Color.G.ToString();      // Green (180) - TextBox
    Blue.Text = Color.B.ToString();       // Blue (209) - TextBox
    Alpha.Text = "100";                   // Alpha (100) - TextBox
    StopText.Text = Stop.ToString();      // Read-only (1) - TextBox
    switch(Convert.ToInt16(StopText.Text))
    {
        case 1: Stop1.BackColor = Color; break;  // Small light blue rectangle - PictureBox
        case 2: Stop2.BackColor = Color; break;  // Small dark blue rectangle - PictureBox
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? It's a bad practice to assume everyone in C# world knows PHP. Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking..

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically reference the form element based on the contents of a text box with type `int`, instead of using a `switch`?

Comment: I agree with @Neolisk, please be more specific.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow @Neolisk I don't really know how I can be more specific. I want to know if there is a way to collapse the 4-line `switch` into 1 cohesive line of code.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: I still don't understand what you want. You need to describe at a higher level, for us to help you. It's not like SO is full of experts who are collapsing N-line switch into M cohesive lines to code on a daily basis.

Comment: @Neolisk Is there a way I can eliminate the `switch`? So as to only have a single line of code in place of that block? I.e. dynamically reference the relevant `PictureBox`'s `BackColor` property

Comment: @DannyBeckett: You want me to help you refactor your code without knowing its purpose? What's `Stop1` and `Stop2`? Anyway, they must be controls of the same type. If so, you could create a variable and then  assign it inside the switch clause `case 1: myVar = Stop1` and `case 2: myVar = Stop2`, then do `myVar.BackColor = Color`. I don't see how you can eliminate `switch`. But seeing `case 1` and `case 2`, stored in a TextBox suggests you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I would argue that shortest code does not mean a better code. If there would be only `Stop1` and `Stop2`, so this is just fine. Just change it to `switch(stop)` instead. C# is not a scripting language so you should not be trying to refer to the variable with dynamic name.

Comment: @Neolisk Stop 1 and 2 are the small rectangles on top of the `TrackBar`. I've edited my OP with comments of which field is which on the screenshot.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: now more clear - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().First(x => x.Name.EndsWith(StopText.Text)).BackColor = Color;
```

Comment: Sounds like an overkill to use LINQ for this purpose. But +1 for your courage.

Comment: @Neolisk I'm just trying to delve into C# and see if there are better ways of doing things. Clearly when there are only 2 stops, it's easier to just use a `switch`. But I was wondering for the sake of scalability and to broaden my C# knowledge. Thanks Simon!

Comment: @Neolisk True, however it scales at least :)

Comment: Aside from compile time error detection, which you lose this way, your problems start when somebody entered a space into `StopText.Text`. :)

Comment: @Neolisk It is disabled/read-only....

Comment: @Neolisk Good point, but I generally don't provide for edge case scenario's within my answers. I leave that up to the OP :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm getting an InvalidOperationException: "Sequence contains no matching elements". I've also tried `this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().First(x => x.Name.Equals("Stop" + Stop.ToString())).BackColor = Color;` Where can I begin debugging this? Thanks!

Comment: You can try removing the `OfType` call. I assumed they were picture boxes though..

Comment: The error means there are no controls with a name ending with whatever is in the textbox. Specifically, PictureBoxes.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead When I do `MessageBox.Show(this.Controls.Count.ToString());` I only get `3`. I have 17 controls on the form - what gives? The snippet above is taken from the .cs file for this form. Do `GroupBox`'s or anything like that affect this?

Comment: @DannyBeckett You're correct. In that case, you need to find a way down into the `GroupBox`. If the `GroupBox` is a child of the form for example, you would use: `this.groupBox.Controls.OfType...`. A `GroupBox` is a container, and as such, has child controls of it's own.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thanks a lot, this was perfect. I ended up using `this.GradientPanel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().First(x => x.Name.Equals("Stop" + StopSelected.ToString())).BackColor = Color;`

Answer (score 1):

You could really make your life easier if you reorder sequence of assignments, specifically `StopText.Text` and `StopX.BackColor`.

Then change your usage and pass a PictureBox instead of a meaningless number (1 or 2):

```
public void Populate(Color Color, PictureBox Stop)
{
  Colour.BackColor = Color;             // Bottom left - PictureBox
  Hex.Text = ARGBToHex(Color.ToArgb()); // Hex (#703919) - TextBox
  Red.Text = Color.R.ToString();        // Red (153) - TextBox
  Green.Text = Color.G.ToString();      // Green (180) - TextBox
  Blue.Text = Color.B.ToString();       // Blue (209) - TextBox
  Alpha.Text = "100";                   // Alpha (100) - TextBox

  Stop.BackColor = Color;
  StopText.Text = Stop.Name.Substring(Stop.Name.Length - 1, 1)
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good way of doing it, but the stop text box is required, otherwise how would I know which stop # I was modifying when I play with the values? That being said, it just pushes the problem on to keeping track of the selected stop # in an additional variable.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: If you need that TextBox badly, you can assign it's value based on the name of Stop. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
StopText.Text = Stop.ToString();
switch(Convert.ToInt16(StopText.Text))
{
    case 1: Stop1.BackColor = Color; break;
    case 2: Stop2.BackColor = Color; break;
}
```

Why not do

```
//have an array of 2 Stops called Stops
StopText.Text = Stop.ToString();
if (Stop < Stops.Length)
{
  Stops[Stop].BackColor = Color;
}
```

(and make sure that you use 0 or 1 indexing consistently, etc)

Comment: `Stop1` and `Stop2` are the small rectangular `PictureBox`'s. How do I fit an array into that?

Comment: `PictureBox[] Stops = new PictureBox[2]; Stops[0] = (insert first PictureBox here); Stops[1] = (insert second PictureBox here);` ?